# XSLT 1.0 loop through sub nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm struggling to create a for-each loop, which will list a number of child nodes.
The xml looks like this:

```
<Product>
    <Name>Name</Name>
    <Colors xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <d4p1:string>String one</d4p1:string>
        <d4p1:string>String teo</d4p1:string>
        <d4p1:string>String three</d4p1:string>
        <d4p1:string>String four</d4p1:string>
    </Colors>
    <Price>329</Price>
</Product>
```

and so far I have tried something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:telenor="http://test" exclude-result-prefixes="test msxsl">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Product/Colors"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@d4p1"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But it's not working. Basically, I'm just looking for a list like this:

> String one String two  String three  String four

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Product/Colors/d4p1:string">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```